# Build a regressor with non-numeric targets that converts to numeric values internally

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to build a linear regression model that accepts timestamps as targets and uses seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (`pd.Timestamp(0)`) internally. `predict` should return timestamps.

I tried to make this work with a `TransformedTargetRegressor`. However, I'm running into a `TypeError: invalid type promotion` I cannot resolve.

Demo code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

# helper function to convert a 2D numpy array of seconds to a 2D array of timestamps
def _to_timestamp(seconds: np.ndarray):
    return pd.DataFrame(seconds).apply(pd.to_datetime, unit='s').values

# helper function to convert a 2D numpy array of timestamps to a 2D array of seconds
def _to_float(timestamps):
    deltas = pd.DataFrame(timestamps).sub(pd.Timestamp(0))
    return deltas.apply(lambda s: s.dt.total_seconds()).values

# build transformer from helper functions
TimeTransformer = FunctionTransformer(
    func=_to_float,
    inverse_func=_to_timestamp,
    validate=True,
    check_inverse=True
)

# make a LinearRegression chained with a TimeTransformer
def TimeTargetLinearRegression():
    return TransformedTargetRegressor(
        regressor=LinearRegression(),
        transformer=TimeTransformer
    )

# test run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = TimeTargetLinearRegression()
    X = np.array([[1], [2], [3]], dtype=float)
    y = pd.date_range(start=0, periods=3, freq='s')
    model.fit(X=X, y=y) # raises TypeError
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/actualpanda/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch2.py", line 36, in <module>
    model.fit(X=X, y=y) # raises TypeError
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_target.py", line 185, in fit
    self._fit_transformer(y_2d)
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_target.py", line 139, in _fit_transformer
    self.transformer_.fit(y)
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 125, in fit
    self._check_inverse_transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 102, in _check_inverse_transform
    if not _allclose_dense_sparse(X[idx_selected], X_round_trip):
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1288, in _allclose_dense_sparse
    return np.allclose(x, y, rtol=rtol, atol=atol)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in allclose
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2159, in allclose
    res = all(isclose(a, b, rtol=rtol, atol=atol, equal_nan=equal_nan))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in isclose
  File "C:\Users\actualpanda\.virtualenvs\SomeProject--3333Ox_\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2254, in isclose
    dt = multiarray.result_type(y, 1.)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in result_type
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

I am looking for an answer that explains/resolves the `TypeError` and - in case my approach is flawed - suggests a method for building a regressor that can handle non-numeric targets (given functions for transforming and inverse-transforming).

I know that I can do the transforming and inverse-transforming outside of the regressor, but I want to encapsulate the process within a neat, user friendly model that does not leak its internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of running `y` through the transform function followed by the inverse transform function is compared to the original `y`.

This "round trip" comparison occurs when you set `check_inverse=True`, and it is passed to `np.isclose`.  This is generating the error.

```
y = pd.date_range(start=0, periods=3, freq='s')
y_ = TimeTransformer.inverse_func(TimeTransformer.func(y))

np.isclose(y, y_)
# raises:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-90ab2804af58> in <module>
----> 1 np.isclose(y, y_)

<__array_function__ internals> in isclose(*args, **kwargs)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in isclose(a, b, rtol, atol, equal_nan)
   2264     # This will cause casting of x later. Also, make sure to allow subclasses
   2265     # (e.g., for numpy.ma).
-> 2266     dt = multiarray.result_type(y, 1.)
   2267     y = array(y, dtype=dt, copy=False, subok=True)
   2268

<__array_function__ internals> in result_type(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

The actual error is coming from the `result_type` C-function.  This checks what the result type of an operation will be and is used to allocating new arrays.

```
y2 = np.array(y)
y_ == y2 
# returns:
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True]])

np.isclose(yy, y_)
# raises: TypeError: invalid type promotion

np.core.multiarray.result_type(y_, 1.)
# raises: TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

My guess is that the `np.datetime64` dtype is not implemented for this method.

I've opened an issue on the github page.

Comment: Thank you. I tried setting `check_inverse=False`, any idea why I still get the same error?

Comment: Update: One needs to set `check_inverse=False` for both the `FunctionTransformer` and `TransformedTargetRegressor` call.